# Cypress cy.wait with alias

Tags: api, request, cypress, alias, wait

I would like to extract a big json file via API in Cypress. The following code (without the cy.wait()) works for small files. Once the file gets bigger and the response time grows over 30 seconds, the script times out.

Therefore I added cy.wait('@api_call')

```js
describe('Api request', () => {
    it('get json', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api_endpoint',
            headers: {
                'API-KEY': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            }
        }).as('api_call')
        cy.wait('@api_call').its('response.body').should('contain','name')
                .then(response => {
            var someArr = new Array();
             someArr = response.body;
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testdata.txt', someArr);
        })
    })
})
```

Now this throws the error

```
cy.wait() only accepts aliases for routes.
```

How can I correctly tell Cypress to wait for the request to resolve?

[edit]I have now tried adding every possible timeout setting from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts and setting them to 90000ms, but it still would not increase the timeout. It still times out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like my fault was how I used the timeout option

```js
describe('Api request', () => {
    it('get json', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api_endpoint',
            headers: {
                'API-KEY': 'xxxxxxx',
            },
            timeout: 90000 <-----
            },
        )
            .then((response) => {
                var someArr = new Array()
                someArr = response.body
                cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testdata.txt', someArr)
            })
    })
})
```

If you put the timeout option there, it will work as intended.

Now it waits for up to 90s which is enough for my purposes.

Comment: Hey that's great, you were able to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, but you gave me the right pointers. I was not aware that you can put individual timeouts in cypress commands

Answer (score 2):

You can add a global timeout for `responseTimeout` in your `cypress.json` like:

```js
{
  responseTimeout: 30000
}
```

Or, you can add timeout individually as well -

```js
describe('Api request', () => {
  it('get json', () => {
    cy.request(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api_endpoint',
        headers: {
          'API-KEY': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        },
        timeout: 30000
      },
    ).as('api_call')
    cy.get('@api_call')
      .its('response.body')
      .should('contain', 'name')
      .then((response) => {
        var someArr = new Array()
        someArr = response.body
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testdata.txt', someArr)
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried both ```responseTimeout: 90000``` in the cypress.json and adding ```{timeout: 90000}```
The script still times out after 30 seconds though

Comment: How about you add timeout in `cy.get()` like `cy.get('@api_call', {timeout: 30000})` OR add `requestTimeout: 30000` in cypress.json ?

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. I added all 4 and set them to 90000 ms. Still the script times out after 30 seconds

Comment: Then may be there is some other issue, because you are adding both request and response timeouts.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I added every single timeout from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts now and set them all to 90000ms and none helped. I have a timeout in both the request and the get part. This is really weird